# Loop to search and display certain parts of array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble making a loop or even if statement to search through an array and then if it returns the value of it, it displays it along with the word before and after.

For example:

```
String Criminals[] = {
    "John Doe, Theft, 1990",
    "Marry Al, Arson, 1970",
    "Sal Don, Theft, 1961"
};
```

it searchs for theft and then it will get the name and date as well, and find the rest if there are any: and the output in this case would be:

Results (2):

```
John Doe, Theft, 1990
Sal Don, Theft, 1961
```

Comment: Please post the code that is not working

Comment: You can use `HashMap`. You can specify its value and key to find it.

Comment: Looks like a Custom class instead of a String will help you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`for`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop to iterate the array and [`String.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) to see if items contain your search term. The only vaguely interesting part is converting all the strings involved to a particular letter case; e.g., lower case, in order to make the search case insensitive.

```
String searchTerm = ...;
searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
for (String s : Criminals) { // loop
    if (s.toLowerCase().contains(searchTerm)) { // find
        System.out.println(s); // display
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked perfectly.